# Grouping an array of dates by year

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

[image]
I am working on an Angular 12 project (typescript). I need to do different types of grouping.
I have an array as below.

```
 [{start: "2021-08-11T20:00:00+00:00", end: "2021-08-17T20:00:00+00:00"},
  {start: "2021-07-04T20:00:00+00:00", end: "2021-07-08T20:00:00+00:00"},
{start: "2021-06-07T20:00:00+00:00", end: "2021-06-13T20:00:00+00:00"},
{start: "2021-04-30T20:00:00+00:00", end: "2021-05-06T20:00:00+00:00"},
 {start: "2020-05-31T20:00:00+00:00", end: "2021-06-13T20:00:00+00:00"},
 {start: "2019-05-31T20:00:00+00:00", end: "2019-06-13T20:00:00+00:00"},]
```

The output should be as below:

```
2021
Aug 11 – Aug 17
11,12,13,14,15,16,17

Jul 4 – Jul 8
4,5,6,7,8

Jun 6 – Jun 13
6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13

Apr 30 – May 06
30,1,2,3,4,5,6

2020
May 31 – Jun 13
31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13

2019
May 31 – Jun 13
31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
```

Thanks in advance.
(Sample image is attached)

Comment: Did your array sort?

Comment: Where did you get Aug 8??

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: All you have to do is parse the year from the date string and then group using that number. Could you please post your code and explain which part you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned an exception for the date where start and end years are different, I have sorted the data using `start` date only.

```
var arr = [
  {
    start: "2021-08-11T20:00:00+00:00",
    end: "2021-08-17T20:00:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    start: "2021-07-04T20:00:00+00:00",
    end: "2021-07-08T20:00:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    start: "2021-06-07T20:00:00+00:00", 
    end: "2021-06-13T20:00:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    start: "2021-04-30T20:00:00+00:00",
    end: "2021-05-06T20:00:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    start: "2020-05-31T20:00:00+00:00",
    end: "2021-06-13T20:00:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    start: "2019-05-31T20:00:00+00:00",
    end: "2019-06-13T20:00:00+00:00"
  },
];
 
var grpArr = {};


for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if(grpArr[arr[i]['start'].substring(0, 4)] == null)
    grpArr[arr[i]['start'].substring(0, 4)] = [arr[i]];
  else
    grpArr[arr[i]['start'].substring(0, 4)].push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(grpArr);
```

NOTE: Here I have considered start and date as a string.

```
Output:

{
  '2019': [
    {
      start: '2019-05-31T20:00:00+00:00',
      end: '2019-06-13T20:00:00+00:00'
    }
  ],
  '2020': [
    {
      start: '2020-05-31T20:00:00+00:00',
      end: '2021-06-13T20:00:00+00:00'
    }
  ],
  '2021': [
    {
      start: '2021-08-11T20:00:00+00:00',
      end: '2021-08-17T20:00:00+00:00'
    },
    {
      start: '2021-07-04T20:00:00+00:00',
      end: '2021-07-08T20:00:00+00:00'
    },
    {
      start: '2021-06-07T20:00:00+00:00',
      end: '2021-06-13T20:00:00+00:00'
    },
    {
      start: '2021-04-30T20:00:00+00:00',
      end: '2021-05-06T20:00:00+00:00'
    }
  ]
}
```